# Why do Windows Forms controls block preview events in a WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, touch

If I have a Windows Forms control like this:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Button button = new System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        {
            Width = 1000,
            Height = 1000
        };

        Host.Child = button;
```

And I subscribe to events like this:

```
    PreviewStylusDown="Window_PreviewStylusDown"
    PreviewStylusUp="Window_PreviewStylusUp"
    PreviewTouchDown="Window_PreviewTouchDown"
    PreviewTouchUp="Window_PreviewTouchUp"
```

I thought surely my WPF window should receive the events. And yet when the button is touched, the events are never raised.

How can the Winforms control absorb a preview event like PreviewTouchDown? If it's a preview, doesn't that mean it's raised in the tunneling phase? Doesn't that mean the window should receive the event before it ever reaches the WindowsFormsHost? Just what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the book [Pro WPF 4.5 in C#: Windows Presentation Foundation in .NET 4.5](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=aPB9aEsLmMEC&pg=PA980&lpg=PA980&dq=WPF+event+WindowsFormsHost+not+fired&source=bl&ots=cvKNFz1tkx&sig=Dl4EZNqQkBVCSjjL0IUMq4HdukA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicm-Wa0dPUAhVJnpQKHW2SABgQ6AEIRTAE#v=onepage&q=WPF%20event%20WindowsFormsHost%20not%20fired&f=false)

[image]

Comment: While this doesn't address tunneling and preview events directly, it still sheds some light on the issue. If they're treated as separate windows, it sort of makes sense that tunneling wouldn't apply because the WinForms control isn't treated as a child of the WPF window and therefore wouldn't take part in tunneling, targeting, or bubbling. This also explains why the control appears in front of all WPF controls no matter how you try to layer them.

Comment: They already make their best effort to glue things from two different worlds together.  :) The concept of event tunnelling is not even tangible in Winforms, right? Oh yes, I come to realize you question is about why the Preview events don't fired from the root element of the WPF visual tree, I donno